# Eu tenho uma variavel atribuida por parametro. Como eu uso ela em botões (Action Performed)?

Tags: java, swing, variáveis

Eu recebi essa variavel (por parametro) de um outro JFrame:

```
public App(int id) {
        System.out.println("teste: "+id);
        /* codigo aqui... */ 
}
```

e queria usar dentro desse 'action performed button':

```
private void MostrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int local = id;
        /* codigo aqui... */ 
    }
```

Como eu faço? Passo ele pra static dentro da .class? mas como isso é feito?

Answer (score 0):

Vale lembrar que um JFrame nada mais é do que uma classe. Essa classe pode ter atributos declarados no seu inicio antes mesmo do seu construtor..
Então uma forma fácil de se manter esse "id" passado para esse JFrame seria ter uma váriavel fora do construtor.

exemplo:

```
public class UmFrameQualquer() extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    int id;  //variável criada para alocar o valor "id" que virá externamente
    public UmFrameQualquer(int id_){
        initComponents();
        id = id_;  //nesse momento o valor "id_" ja está salvo na nossa variável podendo ser acessada em qualquer lugar da nossa JFrame
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu acabei aprendendo a usar Action Listener e o Action Performed. :) resolveu.
ficando assim:

```
public App(int id) {
  jButton.AddActionListener(...){
    Action Performed(){
       /*ação do botão com o 'id'*/
    }
  }
}
```